# Remove only offensive emojis

Tags: ios

How can I remove offensive emojis from my keyboard.  I do not want to remove them all, only those I find offensive.

I could also see someone using this to reduce the volume or make it easier to prefer or select a subset of emoji.

Can I visually suppress or remove one or more emoji?